# Duplicate primary key issue with UTF-8 data

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

We have a table called `site_tags` with a primary key made up of 2 fields - `id` and `tag`.

Some of the `tag` fields are in UTF-8 which we want to convert to ISO-8859-1.

In this table there are 2 tags `Seany` and `seÃ¡ny` and we want to convert the latter from UTF-8.

When we try to do this using...

```
DELETE FROM site_tags WHERE id = '1325133476' AND tag = 'seÃ¡ny'

INSERT INTO site_tags (id, tag, active) VALUES ('1325133476', 'seány', '0')
```

MySQL gives the error on the insert:

```
Duplicate entry '1325133476-seány' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

This seems because it is finding the `Seany` tag so thinks it's a duplicate, MySQL is not being character set sensitive (even though the delete worked on the correct record).

The database is using the `latin1_swedish_ci` collation and MySQL is v5.1 (InnoDB)

Any advice on how we can acheive this?

Comment: `id` is already unique. Why do you need `AND tag = 'seÃ¡ny'`?

Comment: Primary key can be on more than one field. lol

Comment: one learning question: How did you added primary key with combining 2 fields? May b i have heard first time.. :)

Comment: what output do you get if you try an `update` rather than a `delete` and `insert`?

Comment: The same error message as the insert

Comment: does the table have any other restraints? is tag a foreign key?

Comment: Try SET CHARACTER SET utf8; SET NAMES utf8 before your queries

Comment: @fire Forgive me I thought `id` was PK. It seems kinda strange structure to me, anyway.

Comment: what about `SELECT * FROM site_tags WHERE id = '1325133476' AND tag like 'se%ny'`

Comment: @Stu no there is an index on a different field that is it

Comment: Given that it complains of a duplicate key, what if you change the delete to `DELETE FROM site_tags WHERE id = '1325133476' AND tag = 'seány'`? Although if that works I'm not sure why the exercise would be necessary at all...

Comment: @Waygood the delete is working, that's the point! Using set names is surely wrong because we don't want the data inserted in utf8

Comment: Noticed that too and removed the "DELETE isn't working comment", but you beat me to the why

Comment: @DaveRandom the delete worked, it removed the correct record it just won't insert

Comment: if it's giving a duplicate key error on the insert, are you sure the delete worked?

Comment: yes i can see it's no longer in the database, the `Seany` tag is but `seÃ¡ny` is not

Comment: why PHP tag is on this question? are you executing also the tests from PHP?

Comment: @LuisSiquot yes I am writing the code to utf8 decode the tag and update it in PHP

Comment: If the seány is in the database then inserting seány will fail!

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: may be your php convertion way (functions) please paste here

Comment: @Waygood again... `Seany` is in the database, `seÃ¡ny` is no longer there and we are trying to insert `seány` please note the differences

Comment: that is becouse php is converting seÃ¡ny to Seany before it passed to mysql

Comment: What is the collation and character set of the field in the database?

Comment: do you concatenate? do you use PDO? other library?

Comment: Sorry its confusing to show you deleting one entry and then inserting a different entry with a similar spelling. What happens to the data with a REPLACE?

Comment: It replaces the original `Seany` record with it

Comment: @Matthew all set to `latin1_swedish_ci`

Answer (score 0):

I would expect an UPDATE statement to work, but I might be missing something. (I don't have to deal with character sets very much.) Alter your foreign keys to cascade updates if you need to. Untested . . .

```
update site_tags 
set tag = 'seány'
where id = '1325133476' AND tag = 'seÃ¡ny';
```

But I think **the safer approach** might be to create a new column that has the right encoding,  update it through [MySQL's convert() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-convert.html), then fix up the keys. (Create a new column, create a unique constraint on {id, new_column}--that's in addition to the existing constraints--update the new column, etc.)

```
update site_tags
set new_column = convert(tag using latin2)
where new_column is null;
```

I'm not sure latin2 is right; [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-charsets.html) describe it as "ISO 8859-2 Central European".

If you still get duplicate key errors, I'd expect to find that two different values in UTF8 map to a single value in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: The first UPDATE statement we tried originally and produces the same error message

Comment: Or REPLACE as this inserts if not present OR INSERT IGNORE (its on the related list on the right)

Answer (score 0):

It must be the way PHP is passing the concatenated string to MySql. Please, to debug, use echo instead of mysqli.query (or whatever) and be sure (that at least for debugging purposes) you are using the same charset on header and connection

```
mysqli.query(SET CHARACTER SET latin1;);     // latin1 matches ISO-8859-1 on mysql connection
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

Comment: The php is irrelevant, doing the queries in phpMyAdmin has the same effect